# How to run heavy logic inside a sorting function one time only

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, performance, sorting

I need to sort an array of objects based on multiple date fields. Depending on category I sometimes need to exclude some dates.

I would like to avoid the *getUsefullJobTimesForCategory* function being called so many times, since for a single object the result will always be the same.

*Current solution:*

**Sorting main function**

```
private sortForCategory = (category: string) => (a: RefreshDto, b: RefreshDto) => {
    let jobTimesA: Date[] = this.getUsefullJobTimesForCategory(a, category);
    let jobTimesB: Date[] = this.getUsefullJobTimesForCategory(b, category);

    return this.sortByEarliestJobTimeForCategory(jobTimesA, jobTimesB);
    
  }
```

**Getting required dates valid for sorting**
*This is the part I would like to do only once per object,

now it will run for every comparison (which is multiple times per entry)*

```
  private getUsefullJobTimesForCategory(dto: RefreshDto, category: string): Date[]{
    //Heavy calculation
  }
```

**Inner sorting logic once the required dates are known**

```
  private sortByEarliestJobTimeForCategory= (jobTimesA: Date[], jobTimesB: Date[]) => {

    //Custom sorting of Date arrays
  }
```

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand quite everything from your code, I'm not used to typescript, but it seems to me you could use a debounced function ? https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

Comment: Please reduce the code in the question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem with simple, clear function names. Ideally, make the MRE **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). But basically, if `this.getUsefullJobTimesForCategory(a, category);` returns the same thing each time you call it for `a` and `category`, do that once and remember those results, then use those results in the sort callback. That means having a way to pass those results to the two levels of sort functions you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if `this.getUsefullJobTimesForCategory(a, category);` returns the same thing each time you call it for `a` and `category`, do that once and remember those results, then use those results in the sort callback. That means having a way to pass those results to the two levels of sort functions you're using. Since you can't pass extra information directly to the callback via the `sort` method, that means creating a new sort function for the operation that *closes over* the extra information you want to provide.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
// A stand-in for the expensive operation
function expensiveOperation(obj) {
    // Busy wait -- DON'T DO THIS IN REAL CODE
    const stop = Date.now() + 50;
    while (Date.now() < stop) {
    }
    return obj.value;
}

// A version of the sort function that repeats the expensive operation
function simpleSortFunction(a, b) {
    return expensiveOperation(a) - expensiveOperation(b);
}

// An array to sort (we make copies)
const sourceArray = [
    {"value": 11},
    {"value": 13},
    {"value": 17},
    {"value": 19},
    {"value": 7},
    {"value": 3},
    {"value": 6},
    {"value": 19},
    {"value": 12},
    {"value": 12}
];

console.log("Running");

// Doing it without optimization
setTimeout(() => {
    console.time("without optimization");
    const array1 = sourceArray.slice();
    array1.sort(simpleSortFunction);
    showResult(array1);
    console.timeEnd("without optimization");
}, 0);

// A function that creates a sort function that gets the expensive
// information once and reuses it
function getSortFunction(array) {
    // Loop through once doing the expensive operations
    const map = new Map(array.map(obj => [obj, expensiveOperation(obj)]));
    return function simpleSortFunction(a, b) {
        // Use the results
        return map.get(a) - map.get(b);
    };
}

// Doing it with optimization
setTimeout(() => {
  console.time("with optimization");
  const array2 = sourceArray.slice();
  console.time("getting expensive values");
  const memoizedSortFunction = getSortFunction(array2);
  console.timeEnd("getting expensive values");
  array2.sort(memoizedSortFunction);
  showResult(array2);
  console.timeEnd("with optimization");
}, 0); // Won't run until the previous one finishes

// Just a function to show sorting results
function showResult(array) {
    console.log(array.map(({value}) => value).join(", "));
}
```

That example only has to do it for one level rather than two, but you just repeat the same sort of thing as `getSortFunction` for the second level.

Comment: You really should use `WeakMap` for caching, then if the object is discarded, the computed value is also discarded.

Comment: This is an easy to read, clean solution. But the lookup in the maps costs some time. In most cases this **lookup-time** will be negligible. Otherwise the calculated value could be stored as attribute of the objects we want to sort or in a wrapper-object.

Comment: @Akxe - There's no reason for using `WeakMap` in the above. The `Map` is discarded when the memoized sort function is discarded, which is presumably immediately when the code is done with it.

Comment: @slartidan - True. The lookup is ***extremely*** fast, but not free. If you can add a property to the object being sorted you can avoid it. If not, as you say, a wrapper object could be used but then you have the cost of doing an extra map call on the sorted result to get the original objects back. So lots of ways to do it. :-)

Comment: @slartidan The lookup speed must by spec be sub-linear, it is almost on par with `obj.key` access. Do not overoptimalize code, does this access cause an actual problem for you?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe, but it is better to be safe than sorry. Weak alternatives are ideal for cache...

Comment: @Akxe - All due respect, but no, in this case it's not better. There's overhead on GC in `WeakMap`s. If you keep the memoized sort function too long, that's the bug to fix -- not using too big a tool for the job.